# How to connect to a SQLite3 db with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite3 and PHP and was wondering whether and how I could connect to a SQLite3 database with PHP.

How would I get the data from the db and would it be possible to output them on a browser screen?
I've been searching the web for a while now, but couldn't find anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');

$results = $db->query('SELECT bar FROM foo');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

Taken from here: [PHP: SQLite3::query - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php)

Comment: Works only for PHP >= 5.3.0 

With older PHP use PDO

Comment: I have the following error: `Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in ...`

Comment: @Elyor Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637614/how-to-enabling-pdo-sqlite-in-php-version-5-4-19-windows and/or this: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php

Comment: Also worth noting that if the db file doesn't exist, php will automatically create it. A nice feature.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is enabled by default with PHP. You have to use the built-in class [SQLite3](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) (you will find some examples on this page).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I have found and I got it directly from the sqlite website:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('sqlite3db.db');

$results = $db->query('select * from db');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

Also if you're looking to include the php results into html like a table cell or something, go as such:

```
$results = $db->query('select * from db');

?>



<?php  while ($row = $results2->fetchArray()) {?> 
<td><h4><?php echo $row['id'];?></h4></td>
<?php } ?>
```