# Delete the first contents in .txt file every 30 seconds

Tags: php

I have a file (usernames.txt) that has every username of my website members, when they submit their usernames, it will be saved in "usernames.txt", the problem is that there are a lot of users submitting there usernames every day, I want a php code or something that will delete the first (at the top) username every 30 seconds automatically (Even though more than 20 usernames are submitted every minute, the script I need will make the "usernames.txt" file smaller and that will make my server a bit faster. :)
It would be really great if someone has or knows the script I am talking about. :)
Thanks

Comment: **Please** check here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php

Comment: Why is it that would want to log the attempts and then delete them? Are they being backed up? If so, could you not just log then all into a time set filename like `usernames-20140110-121500.txt` generated from the last 30 second period?

Comment: If you want to get helped explain properly what you want to achieve

Comment: Usernames.txt is just an example, but the file I am talking about is close to usernames (The file has my users Access Tokens) But in the example, I used "Usernames.txt" instead of Accesstokens.txt :)
And the reason I am deleting the first (at the top) access token because it expires by itself and then it would be useless to be on the "accesstokens.txt" (usernames.txt in example) and it will make the users request slower if there are expired access tokens in the file. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would also ***really, really*** encourage you to look at http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php as @elclanrs suggested. ***Really*** encourage you.

Failing that, and a very far second place suggestion, I'd even recommend trying to use `serialize` and `unserialize`, so you can read the data in and out of the file quicker. You can then read the data in as an array/object using `unserialize`, manipulate it, and put it back in the file using `serialize`.

Further failing that, you would have to read the file into memory (`file_get_contents`), loop through the lines, and remove the first line, and then write the entire file back out. Alternativly, read it in one line at a time (`fopen`), skip the first line, write the rest of the file back to a temporary file (`fputs`), and then swap the files around (`rename`).

Lastly, assuming you're on a *nix system, you could use something like:

```
exec("sed '1d' {$my_file_name}", $result);
file_put_contents($my_file_name, $result);
```

That all being said, you should really look at using a DB. If you don't want a standalone database, you can use sqlite, which will [write the database to a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041737/how-to-connect-to-a-sqlite3-db-with-php):

> $dbhandle = sqlite_open('db/test.db', 0666, $error);

Comment: I have used databases once in my life, so it's really hard for me to switch my website scripts from php to databases scripts, in other words: I suck at databases codes :/

Comment: No time like the present to learn. :-) But there's a couple of other suggestions in there, that may help.