# How to enabling PDO_SQLITE in PHP Version 5.4.19 windows

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I'm trying to enable PDO for SQLite3 on php 5.4.19.  Following this--> http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

uncommented the line in the php.ini file that says:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

;added next line
extension=pdo.so

However, the phpinfo() still says:

```
PDO
```

PDO drivers  no value

I would think it would like the SQLite driver would be listed.

Trying to troubleshoot so I also tried adding this to the php.ini file.
extension=php_pdo.dll
However, there is no such file in the /ext folder and it says this is no longer needed in this version of php.

What step am I missing?

Edit-->

Ok figured this out and it wasn't obvious to any research I did.
First, absolute paths were required which isn't documented anywhere that I could find.  Final settings are:

```
    extension=C:\php\ext\pdo.so
extension=C:\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=C:\php\ext\php_sqlite3.dll
[sqlite3]
sqlite3.extension_dir = C:\sqlite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try restarting your web server. If that doesn't work, check if `extension_dir` is set properly in `php.ini`. If that still doesn't work, check if the proper `php.ini` is being read in the `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: php.ini is fine now...it works fine.  This is everything enabled.

extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll

[sqlite3]
sqlite3.extension_dir = C:\php\ext\php_sqlite3.dll

server has been restarted like 20 times already.

Comment: Maybe for sqlite3.extension_dir is wants:
sqlite3.extension_dir = C:\sqlite\sqlite3.def
??

Answer (score 3):

Uncommenting `extension_dir = "ext"` in `php.ini` worked for me:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"
```

'phpinfo()`no longer shows`PDO drivers : none enabled' and shows `PDO drivers : sqlite` instead.

It also now shows sections for SQLite3 and pdo_sqlite.