# Filter and display the contents of a database in a webpage

Tags: html, database, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I have an sqlite database and date is one of the columns in it. In my webpage, the user needs to be able to select a range of dates, retrieve the rows that are inside that date range, and display that information in the webpage. I've already set up the date inputs, but other than that, I don't know how to go about filtering the database using the date range and then displaying the hits.

[image: Database]

[image: Ranges]

Comment: Can you show your current code?  What does your table(s) look like?

Comment: Thank you.  Can you also show your current code?  What have you tried?

Comment: @dmikester1 My code right now is just the HTML for the  dates inputs and a button to enter the values. I edited to show the database and what the html looks like.

Comment: OK, are you using a server side language to connect to the database?  I'm not super familiar with sqlite3, but assuming it is similar to mysql.

Comment: I know what query to use to get the information out of the database, however, I don't know how to query the db from the browser.

Comment: But what languages are you using?  Are you using just html and javascript?  Or are you using a server side language like PHP as well?

Comment: Right now I'm just using HTML and JS, correct. Have never used PHP, so I don't know if that would be the best option to get this done, or if there's something more suited for it.

Comment: Where is this being done?  On a hosted server?  On your personal PC?  Or is it on the RPi hence your tag?

Comment: It's an apache server on the RPi.

Comment: While it looks like you can access [sqlite3 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript), it looks difficult and a lot of work.  I would highly recommend installing PHP on your RPi and using that to access your sqllite3 DB.  There are tons of great tutorials out there, here is [one](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/how-to-install-web-server-raspberry-pi-lamp/).

Comment: Thank you for setting me on my way, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, and connecting to sqlite3 with PHP is [super easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041737/how-to-connect-to-a-sqlite3-db-with-php)